# what is best xml study guide?

Tags: xml

what is the best xml study guide to start with? am a new beginner to the xml world

Answer (score 3):

You can start here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked w3schools.com

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

[XML Basics - An Introduction to XML](http://www.xmlfiles.com/xml/)

[A Technical Introduction to XML](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/10/guide0.html)

Answer (score 0):

The OReilly-run [www.xml.com](http://www.xml.com) is a great resource, particularly the [technical introduction](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/10/guide0.html). I wouldn't worry about the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/XML/) and specification until you've got a grasp of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I started with ["Professional XML"](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-XML.productCd-0471777773.html); as it isn't very handy to walk reading, it's covers most essential aspects from XML development and usage.

A must have.